# How to set env variables which contain a command using EnvInject plugin of Jenkins

Tags: shell, plugins, jenkins, environment-variables

I have installed the EnvInject plugin of Jenkins.
I add it in the properties content (In script content also doesn't work: echo's nothing)
I able to set environment variable e.g.:

```
TEST="hello world"
```

In shell:

```
echo ${TEST}
Output: Hello World
```

But when I try to put the output of a command in my variable it doesn't work:

```
HOSTNAME=`hostname`
```

In Shell

```
echo ${HOSTNAME}
Output: `hostname`
```

While when I set the environment variable in my shell (without the plugin it works):
In Shell

```
HOSTNAME=`hostname`
echo ${HOSTNAME}
Output: localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From job configuration you should use `Inject environment variables to the build process / Evaluated Groovy script`.

Depending on the configuration you could execute command and save it in map containing environment variables:

```
return [HOSTNAME: 'hostname'.execute().text]
```

or run `Groovy` equivalent:

```
return [HOSTNAME: java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()]
```